# Ссылка vs гиперссылка

Tags: обсуждение, ссылки

1. Когда использовать тот или иной вариант ?
2. Нужна ли правка ссылки в гиперссылку ?

Если ссылка даётся в самом начале вопроса, то думаю его нужно переводить в гиперссылку, чтобы превью вопроса не портился.

Что я имею ввиду:
Что лучше ?

> Доброго времени суток. Давно хотел задать такой вопрос и блаблабла. Ой,что-то лень писать, вот мой вопрос - https://dsfkjsheiweuryewui.com/user212/whatutalkinbout.php

Или

> Доброго времени суток. Давно хотел задать такой вопрос и блаблабла. Ой,что-то лень писать, вот мой [вопрос](http://simg.sputnik.ru/?key=017d857305b8f035a4761009ddc7fc1f2d6ea860)

Comment: Что здесь есть "превью"?

Comment: Представьте, что вопрос начинается с ссылки как в первом варианте...Нужно его переводить в гиперссылку или нет ? И не обязательно по поводу начала. Нужна ли полная ссылка,если есть функция гиперссылки ?

Comment: Т.е. Вы считаете, что первый вариант это не "гиперссылка"?

Comment: Возможно.... До сих пор непонятно, о чём я? Хорошо. Какой вариант вам нравится больше и почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант, где адрес спрятан внутрь, мне кажется предпочтительным, и я сам стараюсь придерживаться именно такого варианта. Но стоит учитывать контекст сообщения, может быть сам адрес является важным моментом и автор хотел обратить на него внимание читателей.

В общем случае, правка будет улучшать эстетическую составляющую сообщения. В частности было бы неплохо поправить таким образом и ссылки локализационного бота в чате.

> [image: Вообще жуть жуткая]

P.S. А ещё надо не забыть убрать "Доброго времени суток."

Comment: подозреваю речь шла про кликабельный и некликабельный вариант

Comment: @Grundy тогда требуется прояснение вопроса. И уточнение ответа по итогам :)

Comment: P.S. @Grundy ошибся! ликуем!

Comment: @Grundy Не ошибается. Он именно это и имел ввиду :)